# Is there a way to modify pixels in a canvas without having to copy the entire buffer?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, buffer

Is there a way to modify specific pixels in a canvas, without having to get the entire buffer with `ctx.getImageData` and then copying it back with `ctx.putImageData`? This is important so I don't need to make such expensive copying operation every frame update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just specify the region you want to modify:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
```

when done just put it back in the same position:

```
ctx.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
```

This will grab a single pixel at x/y:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);

/// turn the pixel into luma
var gray = data[0] * 0.2126 + data[1] * 0.7152 +data[2] * 0.0722;
imageData.data[0] = gray;  /// r
imageData.data[1] = gray;  /// g
imageData.data[2] = gray;  /// b
imageData.data[3] = 255;   /// alpha

/// put back
ctx.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
```

Of course, if a modification means a simple color change of the pixels obviously just use `fillRect()` or `rect()` + `fill()` for many rectangles but if you need to do more complex stuff (which I assume is the case here) a region can be extracted this way.

Comment: Ken, I thought `putImageData` performed a memcpy. How does it work instead?

Comment: @Viclib I don't know if this is optimized internally (ie. Firefox used DirectX (on Windows, probably similar subsystems for other OSes) for many of the gfx ops) but I haven't looked too deep into how it or Chrome etc. copies *regions*. There is the concept of *stride* though.

Answer (score 1):

fastest way to modify individualy some pixels will be to change the `fillStyle`, then use 
`fillRect(x ,y, 1, 1)`.
It is 50 times faster on latest FireFox (!), and 20% faster on latest Chrome.
(http://jsperf.com/fillrect-vs-putimagedata)

**Edit** : The relevant remark of @markE had me update the performance test : http://jsperf.com/fillrect-vs-putimagedata/4.
And indeed when you both change the draw color with a `ctx.fillStyle=...` AND you `fillRect` afterwise, the performances are close or lower to a putImageData on FF and Ch. Yet on Safari the performances are way better with a fillStyle change (but i changed only for the same color... ???).

So using fillRect rather than putImageData makes sense only for uniform color fill on Ch, FF. Safari seems to prefer anyway to avoid using binary representation of the image.

(You might want to test on other devices, and check if the performances drop or not on Safari when colors really change).

Comment: +1 for the jsperf, but could you fork your jsperf and change the fillStyle to a different color during each loop. I ask because I understand that changing the context state (eg fillStyle) is a costly operation